# Variations Javascript not working when single_product_content is loaded via Ajax (WooCommerce)

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In my WooCommerce Shop Templates I am loading the single-product-content dynamically in the archive-product.php page with Ajax. This part is working. 
But the javascript to choose the product variations is missing so I tried to add the script to the html after the successful ajax request. 
I could load the script but I still can not choose a product variation. No events are triggered. Seems like I am missing something...

My Javascript:

```
jQuery('.project-preview').on('click',function(){
    var theId = $(this).attr('data-project-id');
    var div = $('#product-container');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: singleprojectajax.ajaxurl,
        data : {action : 'load_single_product_content', post_id: theId },
        success: function(data){
            div.html(data);
            loadVariationScript();
        },
        error : function() {
        }
    });
});

function loadVariationScript () {
    jQuery.getScript("../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min.js");
    jQuery.getScript("../wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js");
}
```

In functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_add_scripts' );
function child_add_scripts(){
    wp_register_script( 'pa_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/main.js', array('jquery'), true );
    wp_localize_script( 'pa_script', 'singleprojectajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
    wp_enqueue_script('pa_script');
}

function load_single_product_content () {
     $post_id = intval(isset($_POST['post_id']) ? $_POST['post_id'] : 0); 

     if ($post_id > 0) { 
         $the_query = new WP_query(array('p' => $post_id, 'post_type' => 'product'));
         if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
             while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
             wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
         endwhile;
         } else {
             echo "There were no products found";
         }
     }  
     wp_die(); 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_load_single_product_content', 'load_single_product_content'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_single_product_content', 'load_single_product_content');
```

The WooCommerce script "add-to-cart-variations.js":
https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/95139130/

Answer (score 4):

Did you try like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
"use strict";

$('.project-preview').on('click',function(){
    var theId = $(this).attr('data-project-id');
    var div = $('#product-container');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: singleprojectajax.ajaxurl,
        data : {action : 'load_single_product_content', post_id: theId },
        success: function(data){
            div.html(data);
        },
        complete: function(){
            loadVariationScript();
        },
        error : function() {
        }
    });
});

function loadVariationScript() {
    $.getScript("www.yoursitenamehere.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min.js");
    $.getScript("www.yoursitenamehere.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.js");
}
```

});

You used `$` for your AJAX, so it's safe to assume you're already inside the document ready environment. So you don't need to use `jQuery`.

I placed the `$.getScript()` in the `complete` ajax method. Plus you need to include the entire url to your page.

Comment: Just curious why you would want to load the add-to-cart-variation.min.js and add-to-cart-variation.js? It seems like you would just want to load the add-to-cart-variation.min.js. I tested this and it works great for me.

Comment: I just copied the code from the OP, tbh I'd probably do this a bit differently altogether.